# How can i convert ISO time into IST and GMT in android?

Tags: android

Here, is my code to convert ISO to IST and ISO to GMT.

```
Log.e("ISO TIME",""+time);//The time which i got from JSON file.
            //IST TIME ZONE
            Date date=new Date();
            DateFormat format=DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.FULL);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat();
            simpleDateFormat.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'+00':ss");
            date = simpleDateFormat.parse(time.toString());
            format.setTimeZone(simpleDateFormat.getTimeZone());
            Log.e("IST TIME", "" + format.format(date));

            //GMT TIME ZONE
            Date date1=new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf=(SimpleDateFormat)DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL,DateFormat.FULL);
            sdf.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'+00':ss");
            date1=sdf.parse(time);
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
            Log.e("GMT TIME", "" + sdf.format(date1));
```

Here, is my output

```
E/ISO TIME: 2016-01-18T08:40+00:00
E/GMT TIME: 2016-01-18T03:10+00:00
E/IST TIME: Jan 18, 2016 8:40:00 AM India Standard Time
```

Problem is the actual difference between IST and GMT is 5:30
But in my output i was got the difference exactly 5:30

Please, help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: difference is 5:30 you got 5:30. Whats the problem now ?

Comment: In second output i got like this

Comment: E/GMT TIME: 2016-01-19T21:50+00:00
E/IST TIME: Jan 20, 2016 3:20:00 AM India Standard Time

Comment: What kind of format is this: `2016-01-18T08:40+00:00`?

Comment: yahhh but i got it and thanx a lot.

Comment: Hey,I have problem again please give me valid solution.

Comment: My iso time and ist time both are same why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Logic was definitely right.
But i have some suggestion for your.

You need to add 5:30 hours into your GMT time then you will get IST.
Never add you 5:30 hours into your IST time.

Look at this example
your IST time is 8:40 and GMT time is 3:10

1 hour added each operation

In round brackets one hour add for every iteration:

3:10->4:10(1)->5:10(2)->6:10(3)->7:10(4)->8:10(5)

Remaining IST time minutes to complete an hour is 00:20

add 00:20 into 8:10 it will become a 8:30.

take GMT time for addition
3:20

Your code is absolutely right